# captcha google no respeta js

Tags: javascript, captcha

No se si el titulo esta bien , pero mi pregunta es la siguiente.
Resulta que tengo en mi pagina web un codigo donde le impido al usuario ,mediante javascript ,usar el click derecho.
En mi web funciona bien pero no puedo hacer que eso pase tambien en mi capcha, el cual si deja que se presione el click derecho del mouse...
Mi pagina web es:
http://www.sistemasjjortiz.vzpla.net/

```
<script>
document.oncontextmenu = function(){return false} //funcion para bloquear el click derecho del mouse
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El captcha de google carga por medio de un iframe y por 'seguridad' son muy pocas las modificaciones que le puedes hacer. Por eso tu 'sobreescritura' al oncontextmenu no funciona, el iframe hace que el captcha sea independiente de los eventos (este caso) o css provenientes de tu sitio.

Comment: gracias por la info uriel, voy a confirmar esto , si es asi te doy el visto bueno de la respuesta.

Comment: ya lo confirme, gracias uriel (y)